Proportional tile size in heatmap/ggplot geom_tile
I am using a heatmap to present multivariate data using ggplot and specifically geom_tile. I can use the fill as an aesthetic to display one variable, but I would also like to use sizing of the individual tiles to display a secondary variable.
I was able to use linewidth as an aesthetic to mimic the effect, but it is prone to graphical glitches and inconsistencies due to size and scaling differences. The scale must be set very high to show a visible effect, which also renders the legend unusable. I also tried using height and width of the tiles with no success. Is there a better way to deliver a similar effect?
plot <- mpg %>% 
    filter(manufacturer == "audi") %>%
ggplot(aes(
    y = model, x = year)) +
geom_tile(aes(
    fill = cty,
    linewidth = hwy
    ), color = "white") +
scale_linewidth(
    range = c(0, 50), guide = "none")

Computer generated image of heatmap.

Instead of geom_tile, you could use geom_point(aes(size = hwy), shape = 15) (shape no. 15 is a filled square). Override default size mapping with scale_size_continuous(...)

You've got 6 only combinations of model (y-axis) and year (x-axis). How do you want to display the 18 rows of data? You'll have toeither summarise the data on those two variables or use geom_points/tile/rect with jittering.

geom_tile() accepts a width and height aesthetic. There is no scale_width_() or scale_height_(), so use scales::rescale() to map the hwy values to something usable in the 0,1 range:
  geom_tile(
    aes( 
      fill = cty,
      width = scales::rescale(hwy, from = c((min(mpg$hwy)), (max(mpg$hwy))), to = c(0.1, 1)),
      height = scales::rescale(hwy, from = c((min(mpg$hwy)), (max(mpg$hwy))), to = c(0.1, 1))
      )
    )


This works much better for proprional scaling, do you happen to know how to display a corresponding legend?

I'm not sure what a legend for width or height would look like.
